# Is there an R function that reorganizes individuals in a column such that same individuals are grouped together (chronologically)?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset wherein the columns contain the following information; date, individual id, age category. Individuals were recorded at different time periods in their life and hence when arranged chronologically, the same individual is scattered down the column. I would like to obtain a data-frame in R, such that consecutive rows provide information pertaining to an individual chronologically.
I have provided a sample data-frame below. The original dataset contains several thousand entries. Any help is appreciated.

```
indiv_id<-c("A","B","C","A","B")
age_category<-c("Adult","Young","Adult","Young","Adult")

df1<-data.frame(date,indiv_id,age_category)
print(df1)
        date indiv_id age_category
1 07-02-2010        A        Adult
2 01-01-2010        B        Young
3 03-03-2010        C        Adult
4 04-01-2010        A        Young
5 05-02-2010        B        Adult

df2<-data.frame(date=c("04-01-2010","07-02-2010","01-01-2010","05-02-2010","03-03-2010"),
                indiv_id=c("A","A","B","B","C"),
                age_category= c("Young","Adult","Young","Adult","Adult"))
print(df2)
        date indiv_id age_category
1 04-01-2010        A        Young
2 07-02-2010        A        Adult
3 01-01-2010        B        Young
4 05-02-2010        B        Adult
5 03-03-2010        C        Adult
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arrange` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- arrange(df1, indiv_id, date)
```

This will only work if the date variable is set as a date type. If it's a character, you first need to change the data type, which you can do with `lubridate`'s function `dmy`.

```
library(lubridate)
df2 <- mutate(df1, date = dmy(date)) %>% 
       arrange(indiv_id, date)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. It did help with restructuring the data frame. However, I would like to add that the dates are not chronologically ordered, although the individuals are successfully grouped together. Is there anyway I could ensure that the dates are arranged, keeping the individuals grouped?

Comment: Have you tried using the second block of code I posted?

Comment: I have used the second block of code but it still does not arrange each individual age category in ascending order based on date. For example, I would like it to show for a hypothetical individual the following, individual 1 date 01 --> young, date 02 --> sub adult, date 03 --> adult and so on for each individual. Where can I specify in the code that I would like it to follow the age order (i.e. young, sub adult, adult)?

Comment: `arrange(invid_id, date)` is arranging by individual id in the first place, and then by `date`. If you also want to arrange by age category you need to add `age_category` as an argument to that function.

Comment: I did to that. However, I also included arrange(..factor..levels=...) which did the trick. Thank you very much for your help!